# App Store - Are updates automatically released on approval?

Tags: app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

As the question says, I am wondering whether UPDATED apps are automatically released onto the app store once they are approved?

My update is finished and has been tested, and as it takes a few days to approve I would like to submit it for approval now. In the meantime I need to change update a few things on my server, however I do not want the app update to go live until I have finished my server stuff.

Will the app go live immediately or do I get to choose the release date (after approval of course)?

Many thanks

Comment: Adjust your server and client code to work based on specified versions...save yourself some timing headaches

Comment: That's already done to some degree, as I say I just wanted to get the  update submitted to Apple first - since I need to wait for them to approve it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an option to

- choose the release date
- release immediately on approval
- once approved wait until I release it, (wait for you to click the release button so you can make server changes) aka Version Release Control.

This can all be done from iTunes Connect when submitting your application. However, if you select the option to "release when i'm ready" that application approval is only valid for that build. If you upload a new build, it must be re-approved.

Comment: Can the choice being altered after you chose "release immediately" for example?